# MYSQL query in fetching data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of following structure:

[image: category Table]

I want a mysql query to select the category where subcategory = 2171.
Here i want to fetch categories having subcategories ["2171","2172"] and ["2171"] which means that subcategories that includes "2171".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT category FROM myTable WHERE subcategory LIKE( '%"2171"%' )
```

Putting the double quotes around it will stop false matches on something like 21717.